# Show that for $\gamma\rightarrow 1$, $u(x) \rightarrow \ln(x)$ for $\forall x>0$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $u(x) = \frac{x^{1 - \gamma} - 1}{1 - \gamma}$ for $\gamma > 0$.

I start with taking the limit on both sides.

$$\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} u(x) = \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1 - \gamma}-1}{1 - \gamma} = \frac{0}{0}$$

So I can use L'Hopital's rule here but I am not sure how I can take the derivative of $x^{1 - \gamma}$ with respect to $\gamma$. I understand that $f'(x) = a^{x}\ln(a)$ for $f(x)=a^{x}$, but can't seem to apply the formula here.

Comment: Put $1-\gamma=t$ and then $t\to 0$. This reduces the problem to a standard limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{x^{t}-1}{t}=\log x$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! That's a nice trick. But is saying $t \rightarrow 0$ equivalent to saying $\gamma \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: Yes if $t=1-\gamma$ then $t\to 0$ is equivalent to $\gamma\to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\gamma}}\left(x^{1-\gamma}-1 \right)
\\= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\gamma}} \exp(\log(x)(1-\gamma)) 
\\= \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\gamma}}\log(x)(1-\gamma) \right)\exp(\log(x)(1-\gamma)) 
\\= -\log(x)x^{1-\gamma},$$

where I have used the chain rule in the second equality.

Using that you can apply L'Hospital's rule to your original expression to conclude that 
$$\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{1-\gamma}-1}{1-\gamma} = \frac{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\gamma}}\left(x^{1-\gamma}-1\right)}{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\gamma}}\left(1-\gamma\right)} = \frac{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1}-\log(x)x^{1-\gamma}}{\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 1}-1} = \log(x)$$

Comment: This is called a _power utility function_ in economics, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoelastic_utility